# Unity OVRCameraRig Mirroring to Primary Monitor gets stretched after disabling VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

Problem:
I am using the prefab OVRCameraRig from the Oculus SDK with Unity. I use the viewport rect to show the seen view on the main monitor (mirroring), but after I disable the Oculus with VRSettings.enabled = false, the view on the main monitor gets stretched.

Thanks in advance.

OS: Windows
IDE: Unity v5.4.0b25b
Unity Oculus SDK: v.1.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try to reset your camera aspect ratio? This might help:

```
Camera.mainCamera.aspect = Screen.width/Screen.height;
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. The aspect was the problem.